# Create a subdomain in LAMPP

Tags: subdomain, xampp, lampp

How can I create a subdomain in LAMPP ?
for example http://subdomain.localhost/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will help you...

http://frodosghost.com/2009/09/16/setting-up-xampp-for-subdomains/

Make sure to backup httpd.conf or other .conf file before editing, coz if it went wrong, the apache server won't even start.